# Short-link to FAQ topic

Tags: support, magic-links

When I review posts, I sometimes link to the how-to-ask section or to the mcve section in the Stack Overflow FAQ. The creation of the link, however, is quite different.

When creating a link to the mcve section, it is sufficient on Stack Overflow to write `[MCVE]` as a kind of short-link.

When creating a link to the "how to ask" section, one has to provide the full link as `[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)`. The pseudo-short-link `[how-to-ask]` will not work.

Is there an overview for the existing short-links to FAQ pages on Stack Overflow?

PS: When creating this post, I found that the MCVE short-link will not work on meta, but it definitely works on Stack Overflow!

Comment: The full list of comment short-links here: [Markdown Editing Help - Comment formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: You can shorten links by removing `http://stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`[ask]` is the magic link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

For the full list of magic links, see [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in the editing help.

Comment: This is an old question but one thing I've noticed is that for example I put [joomla.se]  it just says Joomla so then I have to explain that the link is to the SE site not to the Joomla web page or help site.  It would be better if the test was also Joomla.se.

Comment: @Elin I have requested (in the last week) for the `[joomla.se]` to produce `Joomla Stack Exchange` instead of `Joomla`.  Alas, ◇JNat entertained, investigated, then refused that request.

Comment: That's really frustrating since it is very confusing. I always think that users will think that it the Joomla.org web page.